# Does Facebook reuse/recycle access tokens after they expire?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Assume a user's FB access_token has expired for some reason (expiration time is past, user changed password, user removed app from their dashboard, etc). Am I guaranteed that this access_token will never be given out to any user again?

Comment: I would guess that those tokens are generated randomly, so while there is no guarantee that you won't run into a birthday paradox situation, chances are very slim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access tokens can be decoded by the Facebook debugger. This hints that they are a hash of some data, including the user, the scope granted, the requesting app and the expiration time.

With this protocol, there should be no duplication of access tokens. However, that does not mean that Facebook won't change their protocol in the future, which *could* result in a duplicate. This seems pretty unlikely.